# How to send raw post data in a Rails functional test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, testing

I'm looking to send raw post data (e.g. unparamaterized JSON) to one of my controllers for testing:

```
class LegacyOrderUpdateControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "sending json" do
    post :index, '{"foo":"bar", "bool":true}'
  end
end
```

but this gives me a `` NoMethodError: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for #<String:0x00000102cb6080> `` error.

What is the correct way to send raw post data in `ActionController::TestCase`?

Here is some controller code:

```
def index
  post_data = request.body.read
  req = JSON.parse(post_data)
end
```

Comment: I'm curious how you do this, too, for testing a JSON-based API.

Comment: @Brian The answer that is marked as the best accepted answer is no longer correct. Could you update this? You should probably pick an answer that uses the `body` parameter. This is the best way to do it in Rails 5 and Rails 6.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I ran across the same issue today and found a solution.

In your `test_helper.rb` define the following method inside of `ActiveSupport::TestCase`:

```
def raw_post(action, params, body)
  @request.env['RAW_POST_DATA'] = body
  response = post(action, params)
  @request.env.delete('RAW_POST_DATA')
  response
end
```

In your functional test, use it just like the `post` method but pass the raw post body as the third argument.

```
class LegacyOrderUpdateControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "sending json" do
    raw_post :index, {}, {:foo => "bar", :bool => true}.to_json
  end
end
```

I tested this on Rails 2.3.4 when reading the raw post body using

```
request.raw_post
```

instead of

```
request.body.read
```

If you look at the [source code](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/request.rb#L381) you'll see that `raw_post` just wraps `request.body.read` with a check for this `RAW_POST_DATA` in the `request` env hash.

Comment: Make sure you're using request.raw_post (as in this answer) instead of request.body when parsing the JSON in your controller, or you'll get a weird error about "can't convert StringIO into String".

Comment: For some reason this doesn't always play nicely with Devise - investigating the cause, but it works for me everywhere *except* in tests.

Comment: I haven't tried the above solution, but on Rails 3.2.11, a certain other answer on this question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4667097/199712) worked for me.

Comment: `begin; ... ensure` around the `post` call might be a good idea.

Comment: In Rails 4, this is no longer necessary. If the second arg passed to `post` is a String, it will be treated as the `RAW_POST_DATA`.  e.g. `post :create, '{"foo": "bar", "bool": true}'`

Comment: @RyanMcGeary for POST, the new syntax works but for PUT where you need to pass the id in the hash, the new syntax doesn't work.

Comment: In case it helps anyone, this was the best answer years ago. With Rails 5+ it got a lot easier: `post :create, body: '{"foo": "bar", "bool": true}'`

Comment: Speaking of Rails 4. Deleting `RAW_POST_DATA` is not needed since they
[recycle](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.11.3/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L616)
the request object. Also I'd call the method `post_json` and do `to_json` in the method.

Answer (score 28):

Version for Rails 5:

```
post :create, body: '{"foo": "bar", "bool": true}'
```

See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-get) - `body` string parameter is treated as raw request body.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine in Rails 5.2+. Data is accessible in controller as request.raw_post.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine in Rails 6.0. IMO this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: It works in Rails7 as well, unlike all other methods listed in this thread and various blog posts.

Answer (score 20):

I actually solved the same issues just adding one line
before simulating the rspec post request. What you do
is to populate the "RAW_POST_DATA". I tried to remove 
the attributes var on the post :create, but if I do so,
it do not find the action.

Here my solution.

```
def do_create(attributes)
  request.env['RAW_POST_DATA'] = attributes.to_json
  post :create, attributes
end
```

In the controller the code you need to read the JSON is 
something similar to this

```
  @property = Property.new(JSON.parse(request.body.read))
```

Comment: great! Just one line, and I had it work even without the `attributes` sent in to post.

Comment: this worked for Rails 3.2.x , but seems hack-ish. RSpec should support attributes being posted as JSON. Rspec bug?

Comment: Rails 4. For `:create` requests (those that contain no params in the url) one shouldn't need to duplicate attributes. You can get away with `post :create, attrs.to_json`. For `:update` you can do it your way, but `RAW_POST_DATA` needs only those attributes that are needed in the body, `post` only those needed in the url (`request['RAW_POST_DATA'] = body_attrs.to_json; post :update, url_attrs`).

Answer (score 12):

For those using Rails5+ integration tests, the (undocumented) way to do this is to pass a string in the params argument, so:

```
post '/path', params: raw_body, headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
```

Comment: This stopped working for me in rails 5.1. If you looks at request.body.read - it is empty.

Comment: Works in Rails 6

Answer (score 11):

I was searching very long for how to post raw JSON content in a integration test (Rails 5.1). I guess my solution could also help in this case.
I looked up the documentation and source code for the `post` method: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-post

This directed me to the `process` method for more details: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/Session.html#method-i-process

Thanks to this, I finally found out what parameters are accepted by the `process` and thus `post` method.
Here's what my final solution looked like:

```
post my_url, params: nil, headers: nil, env: {'RAW_POST_DATA' => my_body_content}, as: :json
```

Answer (score 10):

Looking at stack trace running a test you can acquire more control on request preparation:
ActionDispatch::Integration::RequestHelpers.post => [ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.process](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb) =>
[Rack::Test::Session.env_for](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test/blob/master/lib/rack/test.rb)

You can pass json string as :params AND specify a content type "application/json". In other case content type will be set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and your json will be parsed properly.

So all you need is to specify "CONTENT_TYPE":

```
post :index, '{"foo":"bar", "bool":true}', "CONTENT_TYPE" => 'application/json'
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I get an error like "undefined method `symbolize_keys' for #<String:0x00000102b4b0d8>"

Comment: Yup, you can take a look at the Rails source for `post` (which calls `process`). If the first arg after the action is a String, it will be read as `RAW_POST_DATA`.

Comment: This works in Rails 4+, not in some earlier versions.

Comment: For Rails 4 it should work for `:index` (or any other route without params in the url) without content type, but won't e.g. for `:update`.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about integration tests. Of that I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using RSpec (>= 2.12.0) and writing Request specs, the module that is included is `ActionDispatch::Integration::Runner`. If you take a look at the source code you can notice that the [post](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4147e0feaddac0e86c9b1f52eec4b1e33d7d6591/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L39) method calls [process](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4147e0feaddac0e86c9b1f52eec4b1e33d7d6591/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L254) which accepts a `rack_env` parameter.

All this means that you can simply do the following in your spec:

```
#spec/requests/articles_spec.rb

post '/articles', {}, {'RAW_POST_DATA' => 'something'}
```

And in the controller:

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb

def create
  puts request.body.read
end
```

Comment: This only works for integration tests and not for functional tests extended from ActionController::TestCase.

Answer (score 2):

Using Rails 4, I was looking to do this to test the processing of raw xml that was being posted to the controller.  I was able to do it by just providing the string to the post:

```
raw_xml = File.read("my_raw.xml")
post :message, raw_xml, format: :xml
```

I believe if the parameter provided is a string, it just gets passed along to the controller as the body.

Comment: I don't know why you are getting downvoted, this is right. The second argument to `post` can be a String or IO, and that becomes the body.

Comment: Although it won't work if your url also contains params (e.g. `:update`).

Answer (score 2):

In rails, 5.1 the following work for me when doing a delete request that needed data in the body:

```
delete your_app_url, as: :json, env: {
   "RAW_POST_DATA" =>  {"a_key" => "a_value"}.to_json
}
```

**NOTE:** This only works when doing an Integration test.

Comment: Delete was a bug in the underlying library.  https://github.com/rack-test/rack-test/issues/200

Answer (score 0):

The `post` method expects a hash of name-value pairs, so you'll need to do something like this:

```
post :index, :data => '{"foo":"bar", "bool":true}'
```

Then, in your controller, get the data to be parsed like this:

```
post_data = params[:data]
```

Comment: I've tried this, it needs to be completely raw though
{"response":"error","errors":"can't parse request: 598: unexpected token at 'data=

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON in your controller? Could you add some controller code to your question?

Comment: I've added a modification to your controller code in my answer.

Comment: This is wrong. If your request body is declared as application/json, then you're reading the body in the controller with request.body.read and params[:data] won't do what you want. Your API is also probably not right either.

Comment: Sounds more like a kludge. You haven't found a way to make the whole body `application/json`, so you're passing `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` that contains a field with a json value.

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 4.1.5, this was the only thing that worked for me:

```
class LegacyOrderUpdateControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    @request.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/json'
  end

  test "sending json" do
    post :index, '{"foo":"bar", "bool":true}'.to_json, { account_id: 5, order_id: 10 }
  end
end
```

for a url at /accounts/5/orders/10/items. This gets the url params conveyed as well as the JSON body. Of course, if orders is not embedded then you can leave off the params hash.

```
class LegacyOrderUpdateControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    @request.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/json'
  end

  test "sending json" do
    post :index, '{"foo":"bar", "bool":true}'.to_json
  end
end
```

Comment: String#to_json means you're passing in a JSON string which contains JSON within it... that's not likely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4 (at least in 4.2.11.3) there's no easy way to test your controllers that consume json (functional tests). For parsing json in a running server the [`ActionDispatch::ParamsParser`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.11.3/railties/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb#L55) [middleware](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.11.3/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb#L43-L46) is responsible. Controller tests though rely on Rack, which can't parse json [to this day](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/v2.2.2/lib/rack/request.rb#L438-L439) (not that it should).

You can do:

```rb
post :create, body_params.to_json
```

or:

```rb
post :update, body_params.to_json, url_params
```

But `body_params` won't be accessible in the controller via `params`. You've got to do `JSON.parse(request.body.read)`. So the only thing that comes to mind is:

```rb
post :update, url_params.merge(body_params)
```

That is, in tests pass everything via parameters (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). In production the body will be parsed by `ActionDispatch::ParamsParser` to the same effect. Except that your numbers become strings (and possibly more):

```rb
# test/controllers/post_controller_test.rb
post :update, {id: 1, n: 2}

# app/controller/posts_controller.rb
def update
    p params  # tests:
              # {"id"=>"1", "n" => "2", "controller"=>"posts", "action"=>"update"}
              # production
              # {"id"=>"1", "n" => 2, "controller"=>"posts", "action"=>"update"}
end
```

If you're willing to parse json in controllers yourself though you can do:

```rb
# test/controllers/post_controller_test.rb
post_json :update, {n: 2}.to_json, {id: 1}

# app/controller/posts_controller.rb
def update
    p JSON.parse(request.body.read)  # {"id"=>"1", "n" => 2, "controller"=>"posts", "action"=>"update"}
end
```

Answer (score -5):

```
post :index, {:foo=> 'bar', :bool => 'true'}
```

Comment: That's not raw JSON, that's the hashed interpretation of it.