# Ruby on Rails: Functional Testing: POST does not send raw XML data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, http-post, functional-testing

I have the following:

```
  @request.env['RAW_POST_DATA']  = data
  @request.env['CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'application/xml' 
  @request.env['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'application/xml'
  post "create", :api_key => api_key, :format => "xml"
```

and test.log shows this:

```
Processing ****Controller#create to xml (for 0.0.0.0 at 2011-07-08 15:40:20) [POST]
  Parameters: {"format"=>"xml", "action"=>"create", "api_key"=>"the_hatter_wants_to_have_tea1", "controller"=>"****"}
```

Which... I guess is fine, but the RAW_POST_DATA doesn't show up as a hash in the parameters list in the log.... now... it works when I call the action from the terminal using curl:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -d '<object><name>Das Object</name></object>' http://notAvailableDuringTesting.butWorksInDevelopmentMode.dev/object.xml?api_key=the_hatter_wants_to_have_tea1
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you figure it out? did my answer help? if not - can you post the solution here for others to learn-from? :)

Comment: I haven't figured it out / have abandoned the test. =\

Comment: I have this exact same issue but I'm posting JSON. Rails parses it correctly if I hit it with cURL but won't from a functional test, no matter what I do.

Comment: This seemed to do the job for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2106677/172106

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you aren't just passing the params to the post call itself? eg:

```
 post "create", :api_key => api_key, :format => "xml", :params => data
```

Controller tests are there to test that the controller action does what it expects when you send it params that you already know of. they generally aren't there to test parsing of xml into params.

If you just want to test the former - then don't bother making them into xml - just pass them as a hash.

If you really do want to test parsing of xml into params - you may need to look into something that operates outside of the scope of rails tests (eg selenium or watir)

Comment: because the controller doesn't parse the XML if you do it like that. or at least, mine doesn't.

Comment: yes - you shouldn't pass it as xml if you do it that way - just as a hash. Of course if the purpose is to pass xml specifically - then I'm not sure what you need to do.