# Rails3: Functional tests fail with NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, functional-testing

I'm using Devise (v2.1.2) with Omniauth for user verification. I'm working on a functional test for a controller that takes a JSON object as the POST body and thus using the technique from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103977/how-to-send-raw-post-data-in-a-rails-functional-test) to set the raw POST body. This works fine for development, but when I run tests I get an exception on a method that's completely unauthenticated:

```rb
NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

Example test:

```rb
test "should be able to create an item" do    
  m = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:item)
  raw_post :create, {}, m.to_json 
  assert_response :success   
end
```

None of my models have a `user` method, and nothing in this controller uses authentication,  so I was pretty confused. A full stack trace shows that the error comes from the first line of this function in Devise:

```rb
def sign_out_all_scopes(lock=true)
  users = Devise.mappings.keys.map { |s| warden.user(:scope => s, :run_callbacks => false) }

  warden.raw_session.inspect
  warden.logout
  expire_devise_cached_variables!
  warden.clear_strategies_cache!
  warden.lock! if lock

  users.any?
end
```

So it looks like in my functional tests (and only in my functional tests) the `warden` object is nil.

1. Why is this function being called on an unauthenticated request?
2. Why doesn't the `warden` object exist here?
3. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. No idea, Devise is doing its own thing.
2. See 1.
3. Include `Devise::TestHelpers`.

The [Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) says that you need to include the helpers in order to use them. It does not say that if you don't include the helpers your functional tests will fail, *including those that don't use any authentication*, but that's what happens.

(Note the JSON handling here, which I originally thought was the problem, ended up being just a red herring. Even with standard post or get you will have this problem.)