# Sending raw post data with RSpec

Tags: integration-testing, rspec-rails

I am trying to POST some raw data in a functional RSpec example:

```
payload = "{wrongly_formatted_json}"
uri = "http://example.com"
headers["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"] = "application/json"
post(uri, payload, headers)
```

RSpec is too smart and wraps my request payload in another hash:

```
{"{wrongly_formatted_json}" => nil}
```

I found people recommending `@request.env['RAW_POST_DATA']` but the request object is not available in my example. Am I right that the @request object comes with ActiveSupport::TestCase and as such can not be used or is it because I include the Rack::Test::Methods?

How can I post raw data with RSpec? Note, I want to send *wrongly formatted* JSON. I am using rspec-rails 2.12.0.

Here is a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103977/how-to-send-raw-post-data-in-a-rails-functional-test) asking the same question but they use ActiveSupport::TestCase to solve it.

Comment: It looks like you're writing a controller spec. (The many spec types are listed in the menu here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-14/docs/) In rspec 2.14.2, at least, in controller specs, the request is available with `request` or `@request`. And setting `request.env['RAW_POST_DATA']` works for me, so this looks like a dupe of that other SO question to me. Or am I missing something?