# How to set the request.body for an Rspec request spec with a GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

- rails 5.0.0.1
- rspec 3.5

I have inherited a code base. I am busy writing integration tests to tie down the app functionality before I consider refactoring.

I have the following lines in a controller concern `before_action`. It seems to read the request body. The `json` value here is used to extract an identifier used to authenticate the request.

```
request.body.rewind
body = request.body.read
json = JSON.parse(body) unless body.empty?
```

I need to test that the authentication happens correctly. 
How can I set the `request.body` for a GET request spec?

Answer (score 7):

I think you should be able to do this via the request env `RAW_POST_DATA`

```
get root_path, {}, 'RAW_POST_DATA' => 'raw json string'
request.raw_post # "raw json string"
```

See: 
[How to send raw post data in a Rails functional test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103977)

Answer (score 3):

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec

@rails_post_5

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Widget management", :type => :request do

  it "creates a Widget and redirects to the Widget's page" do
  headers = { "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json" }
  post "/widgets", :params => '{ "widget": { "name":"My Widget" } }', :headers => headers
    expect(response).to redirect_to(assigns(:widget))
  end

end
```

or just

```
post "/widgets", params: '{ "widget": { "name":"My Widget" } }'
```

Comment: Seems like this isn't really answering OP's question? OP is asking about how to get the body and the example here doesn't include the body (the production code in OP's example doesn't refer to params).

Comment: In Rails, you can access attributes of the body via `params`